# Install dataStax java-driver on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java, apache2, tomcat

I am trying to Install a datastax java-driver on ubuntu 15.04, can anyone advise the best course of action as the github repo does not give a detailed procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would add the java driver as a Maven dependency when you build your Cassandra client application.  That would pull in the jar file for the driver and you could package it with your client application as you see fit.

So in your Maven pom.xml you'd add the version you want as a dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```